# How to do a group by operation on a list of json objects in python?

Tags: python, json, list

I am working on a Python script where I need to group by a key in a list of JSON objects.

I’ve a list of a large number of JSON objects in python in the following format:

[{'name': xyz, 
   'territory': abc, 
    'parameter_a': 1,
    'parameter_b': 2, 
    'parameter_c': 3},
 …]

Now I want to create a tag (say parameter_d) which should say the number in the grouped by count the number of times a specific territory (Say ‘abc’) has occurred in the whole list of json objects.
E.g. Territory abc occurs 3 times in the list, so i want the parameter_d to hold values 1,2,3 for the different instances where the territory abc occurred.
 Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your example string is neither JSON nor Python. In future, please provide correct examples.

Comment: thanks for the help Rob. it is a python list of json objects from my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from json import loads, dumps
from collections import defaultdict

json_string = """
[
    {"name": "xyz", "territory": "abc", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3},
    {"name": "qrs", "territory": "def", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3},
    {"name": "tuv", "territory": "abc", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3},
    {"name": "abc", "territory": "abc", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3}
]"""

# Step 1: convert from JSON to Python:
python_object = loads(json_string)

# Step 2: Add `parameter_d` to each item in list,
# using defaultdict(int) as a counter:
counts = defaultdict(int)
for item in python_object:
    counts[item["territory"]] += 1
    item["parameter_d"] = counts[item["territory"]]

# Step 3: convert from Python to JSON
json_string = dumps(python_object, indent=2)
print json_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this part of Rob's answer for the setup:

```
from json import loads, dumps
from collectins import defaultdict

json_string = """
[
    {"name": "xyz", "territory": "abc", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3},
    {"name": "qrs", "territory": "def", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3},
    {"name": "tuv", "territory": "abc", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3},
    {"name": "abc", "territory": "abc", "parameter_a": 1, "parameter_b": 2, "parameter_c": 3}
]"""

# Step 1: convert from JSON to Python:
python_object = loads(json_string)
```

You could create a dictionary of territories, and then update your object:

```
territories = defaultdict(list)

for i, item in enumerate(python_object):
    territories[item['territory']].append(i)

for item in python_object:
    item['parameter_d'] = territories[item['territory']]

print(dumps(python_object, indent=2))
```